# Why wont my background image appear in firefox, but it will in dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, png

My background image refuses to appear on my the front page of my website. I have checked all the paths, and still cannot figure out what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Coming Soon...</title>
<link href="styles/comingstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/logo.png">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p> <img src="images/comingsoon.png" width="640" height="400" /></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 640px;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
}
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to background.png returns a 403 (forbidden). Change access permissions on that file on your webserver.